# the proof of <the> pudding is in the eating

Tags: articles, usage

> the proof of **the** pudding is in the eating

**Question 1:** What is the role of **the**?

**Question 2:** Is it possible to replace **the** with "a"?

(I am assuming that "proof" means "test".)

Comment: It's a *dictum* - it might owe as much to scansion / prosody as to grammar / syntax.

Comment: Logically, you might think the indefinite article would be at least as appropriate, but it's also relatively uncommon with [*manners make **the** man*.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=manners+make+the+man%2Cmanners+make+a+man&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true)

Comment: And even 150 years after it would have been current usage, "manners maketh the man" is current usage for some of us. It's one of those phrases that have been dragged down through history.

Answer (score 10):

The principle of this idiom is that each individual pudding can be judged on its taste. Some might be good, some might be bad - you'll know when you eat it.

Without the definite article, 'pudding' would be a mass noun and mean *all* pudding everywhere. That wouldn't make sense in the context.

Yes, I suppose you could replace it with the indefinite article and it would still make grammatical sense. It might even make more sense in modern English. But this is an idiom - an old saying - and as such people say it the way it has always been said.

Comment: The point of the idiom is that it's talking about one pudding in particular, not just any pudding.

Comment: @MrLister, so there's some specific pudding somewhere that can be proved by eating it, and all the other puddings in the world can't be proved that way? It's not much of a useful aphorism if it only applies to one particular pudding that was probably eaten centuries ago.

Comment: @MrLister umm no the point of any any analogy is that it can be applied to things it isn't. This doesn't even have to be about pudding. It's literally anything except a specific pudding.